# Can't grab dynamically created elements via querySelector using insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, rendering, queryselector, insertadjacenthtml

I'm trying to grab an element from page and add an addEventHandler to it. Element (link with class .catalog__link) was dynamically created in another external function when the page was loaded using insertAdjacentHTML. I invoke them both in third js file via import keyword. Everything loads perfectly on the page, the elements are created for me, but I can’t grab them from another function connected to the page.  Here’s examples of codes. I have two external function, combined in one js file and simple html page

This is fillCatalog.js (First file)

```
const row = document.querySelector('.catalog__row');

export const fill = function (brand) {
  fetch(`./data/${brand}.json`)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      let products = [...data.products];

      products.forEach(product => {
       
        row.insertAdjacentHTML(
          'afterbegin',
          ` <a class="catalog__link" href="#" >
              <div class="catalog__product">
              <div class="catalog__product-img">
              <img class="catalog__productImg" src=${product['img-src']} alt="" srcset="" />
              </div>
              <h3 class="catalog__product-model">${product['model']}</h3>
              <p class="catalog__product-brand">${product['brand']}</p>
              <span class="catalog__product-price">${product['price']}</span>
              
          </div></a>`
        );
      });
    });
};
```

This is productSave.js (Second file)

```
class Product {
  constructor(cardImg, cardName, cardBrand = '', cardPrice) {
    this.cardImg = cardImg;
    this.cardName = cardName;
    this.cardBrand = cardBrand;
    this.cardPrice = cardPrice;
  }
}

const links = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__link');

export const productSave = function () {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log(links);
    links.forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', e => {
        productItem = link.querySelector('.catalog__product');
        const newProduct = new Product(
          productItem.querySelector('catalog__productImg').src,
          productItem.querySelector('.catalog__product-model').textContent,
          productItem.querySelector('.catalog__product-brand').textContent,
          productItem
            .querySelector('.catalog__product-price-price')
            .textContent.replace(/\D/g, '')
        );
        localStorage.setItem('newCard', JSON.stringify(newProduct));
        console.log(card.querySelector('.card__name').textContent);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

This is third file where I invoke external function

loadContent.js

```
import { fill } from './fillCatalog.js';
import { productSave } from './productSave.js';
fill('jordans');
productSave();
```

Simple HTML

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <!--=include head.html-->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="catalog">
  <div class="catalog__content">
    <div class="catalog__row"></div>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>

  <script type="module" src="../js/goodscart.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="../js/loadContent.js"></script>
</html>
```

I've tried use beforeend afterent and etc. Tried also use getElementsByTag, it returns empty HtmlCollection[]. After insertAdjacentHTML, can't select like usually this links.

Could anyone help me please with this issue? I can't find solution for that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `links`  inside the function to avoid it being initialized before the elements are rendered.

### Initialization of `links`

```
class Product {
...
}

// since this is not in a function it is initialized on import so 
// before you render the `catalog__link` 
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__link'); // <-- This

export const productSave = function () {
// <-- Should be here
...
};
```

### Handling the `fill` Promise

Futhermore there is a fetch reuqest inside `fill` which returned a promise.

Then you can properly chain the call to the following function like so

```
// productSave will only be executed after the 
// fetch from fill has concluded sucesscully
fill('jordans').then(productSave);
```

```
export const fill = function (brand) {
  return fetch(`./data/${brand}.json`).then(...)
  // return as a promise
};
```

### Workaround to detect classes in dom

You can also implement a detector that waits for at least one link to be rendered. This `Promise` would resolve after at least `1` item with `catalog__link` can be found. Then you can chain your logic with `.then(...)`. This one also includes a timeout of 10 seconds which executes `.catch(...)` (if present otherwise throws) if the element was not found in time.

```
new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        clearInterval(interval);
        rej("Not Found")
    }, 10000);
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__link');
        if (links.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        clearInterval(interval);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        res(links)
    },200);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I tried to do as you said and put the initialization inside the function. Unfortunately the result has not changed.

Comment: Thanks @Andy I missed the fetch in between. I will update the response to include a propper handling of the promise

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much,Vincent. You gave me good direction to search solution.

i put it all to setTimeout. And it's working good. I'm not strong enough in JS to use and manipulate promises. Thank you

```
export const productSave = function () {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const links = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__link');

      links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', e => {
          const product = link.querySelector('.catalog__product');

          console.log(product);

          const newProduct = new Product(
            product.querySelector('.catalog__productImg').src,
            product.querySelector('.catalog__product-model').textContent,
            product.querySelector('.catalog__product-brand').textContent,
            product
              .querySelector('.catalog__product-price')
              .textContent.replace(/\D/g, '')
          );

          console.log(newProduct);
          localStorage.setItem('newCard', JSON.stringify(newProduct));
        });
      });
    }, 500);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `fill` is an async process due to the `fetch` but you're calling `productSave` *immediately* after calling it so the DOM hasn't been built by the time the code tries to pick up the elements.
2. Move your links caching within the `productSave` function.

It maybe easier to separate out the asynchronous parts from the synchronous parts. In this example there's a separate `getData` function which is awaited and *then* the data can be filled, and saved.

```js
// `getData` is only responsible for the async process
async function getData(brand) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`./data/${brand}.json`);
    if (res.ok) return res.json();
    throw new Error();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

// `fill` creates the HTML
function fill({ products }) {
  const row = document.querySelector('.catalog__row');
  products.forEach(product => {
    row.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', yourTemplateString);
  });
}

// `productSave` adds the listeners
function productSave() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__link');
  links.forEach(link => ...etc )}
}

// `main` needs to be async because it needs to `await`
// the parsed JSON from `getData` - but after that you can call the
// functions in series
async function main() {
  const data = await getData('jordans');
  fill(data);
  productSave();
}

main();
```